# Check boxes serialization by one index in an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to serialize a form with randomly counted check boxes.
As far as I can see, `$('#selector').serializeArray();` is serializing each checked checkbox per single index in the array (example below). I can't grab this data in PHP, because it always counts check boxes randomly, and I need to know how meany indexes are coming after.

Can I serialize the form and put all check boxes in one index array?

Console log after serialization:

```
9: Object { name: "course", value: "1" }
10: Object { name: "course", value: "2" }
11: Object { name: "course", value: "3" }
```

9,10,11 - There are three indexes, but I need only one index.

Example:

```
9: Object {0- name: "...", value:"...", 1- name:"..." value: "...", etc.}

<form id="my-form">
 <input name="name" type="text" value="my-name">
 <input name="surname" type="text" value="surname">
 <input name="email" type="text" value="email">
 <input type="checkbox" name="course-1" id="" value="1">
 <input type="checkbox" name="course-2" id="" value="2">
 <input type="checkbox" name="course-3" id="" value="3">
 <input type="checkbox" name="course-4" id="" value="4">
 <input type="checkbox" name="course-5" id="" value="5">
</form>


var data = $('#my-form).serializeArray();
console.log(data);
```

I need to serialize the form and get all check boxes which were checked and not. In php it give me:

```
$_POST['course-1']= 1
$_POST['course-2']= 2
$_POST['course-3']= 3
```

Need something like:

```
$_POST['courses']['course-1']= 1
$_POST['courses']['course-2']= 2
$_POST['courses']['course-3']= 3
```

Comment: your question isn't clear maybe come code shown would help

Comment: Your question is very cryptic, also you should have a jquery tag on this, and I don't see any php so I'm not sure why you tagged it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the multiple keys with the same name in a JS Object (`value` in your case).

If you really want **only one** `Object` (I don't recommend it, this is a terrible way), you can use a pattern like the following:

```js
{
  name0: 'course',
  value0: '1',
  name1: 'course',
  value1: '2',
  ...
}
```

To do that, you can just use a `for` loop:

```js
// var selected = $('#selector').serializeArray();
var selected = [
    {
        name: 'course', value: '1'
    }, {
        name: 'course', value: '2'
    }, {
        name: 'course', value: '3'
    }
];

var encapsulated = {};

for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    var item = selected[i];

    encapsulated["name" + i] = item.name;
    encapsulated["value" + i] = item.value;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(encapsulated, null, 2));
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, i will try this way.